# Find the integral part of $\sum_{n=1}^{10^9} {n^{- \frac {2}{3}}}$.

Tags: summation, contest-math, harmonic-numbers

> Find the integral part of $\sum_{n=1}^{10^9} {n^{- \frac {2}{3}}}$.
>
> SOURCE : [Inequalites - CRUX](http://imomath.com/pcpdf/f1/f41.pdf) (Page Number 3 ; Question Number 160)

Wolfram Alpha gives the answer as $\approx 2997.55$   .

For upper bound as $k$ instead of $10^9$, it gives a general formula as $H_k^{ \big({\frac {2}{3}\big) }}$, where $H_n^{(r)}$ i the generalized harmonic number.

So, the answer is essentially $H_{10^9} ^{ \big({\frac {2}{3}\big) }}$.

Can anyone explain how to obtain this answer?

Any help would be gratefully acknowledged :).

Comment: It is the definition ...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt What do you mean ?

Comment: Define generalized harmonic number

Comment: Say, what does "integral part" mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{10^9}\frac1{n^{2/3}}\approx\zeta(2/3)+\int_0^{10^9}\frac1{x^{2/3}}\ dx+\frac1{2(10^9)^{2/3}}\\=\zeta(2/3)+3(10^9)^{1/3}+\frac12(10^{-6})\approx2997.552$$

As for the generalized harmonic number, they are equal by definition, which is rather useless except for the fact that you can now Google about the [generalized harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers).

Comment: :-/ Why the downvote?  I cannot help if I did not understand what "integral part" meant, and I even asked for clarification with no response after 3 hours.

Comment: The downvote is not from me.... I just upvoted you..... Nice answer.. :)

Answer (score 6):

We have, by integral-series estimation, $$\int_1^{10^9+1} x^{-2/3} \,dx < \sum_{1\leq k\leq 10^9} k^{-2/3}<1^{-2/3}+\int_1^{10^9} x^{-2/3} \,dx$$
So
$$\left.3\sqrt[3]{x}\right|^{10^9+1}_1 < \sum_{1\leq k\leq 10^9} k^{-2/3} < 1+\left.3\sqrt[3]{x}\right|^{10^9}_1$$
So
$$2997<3\sqrt[3]{10^9 + 1} - 3 < \sum_{1\leq k\leq 10^9} k^{-2/3} < 2998$$
So the integer part of the sum is $\boxed{2997}$

Comment: Oh... integer part!  Jeez I am stupid...